# The meaning of: a program P posseses a property R

Tags: program-analysis

I am reading an article called [The temporal semantics of concurrent programs](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science?_ob=MiamiImageURL&_cid=271538&_user=32321&_pii=0304397581901109&_check=y&_origin=article&_zone=toolbar&_coverDate=31-Dec-1981&view=c&originContentFamily=serial&wchp=dGLzVlV-zSkWb&md5=2073f527aa2be434886953d7aaa0f7d3&pid=1-s2.0-0304397581901109-main.pdf)
.

> A construction is then given for assigning to a program P a temporal
> formula W(P) which is true on all proper execution sequences of P.
>
> In order to prove that a program P posseses a property R, one has only
> to prove the implication $$W(P)\supset R$$
> My question is this: Didn't they get the containment the other way
> around ?

If I understand correctly, a property,R, is a set of traces, for P
to hold the property each trace of P needs to be in R, hence $$W(P)\subset R$$

Do I understand something wrong here, or is there a mistake in the

Comment: This is definitely not a research-level question. It's about ambiguity of notation. I have added an answer nonetheless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot see the article and have to guess. The text makes clear that they are using the symbol $\supset$ as notation for implication. So you could read it as

> In order to prove that a program $P$ possesses a property $R$, one has only to prove the implication 
>   $W(P) \implies R$.

See the Wikipedia page on [material implication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional) for other notation for implication.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have edited the link in the question. I hope it works now.